# Validity sensors (wbf) (pid=0050) api for .Net software development c#

Tags: c#, .net, device, sensors, fingerprint

We have an HP Envy 15-J138TX laptop which comes with an embedded fingerprint sensor from Validity. The HP SimplePass application works perfectly fine with the sensor. I need to integrate the sensor with my own .NET C# application so that I can save fingerprint images using this fingerprint sensor and work on the images for post processing. I did the same with an earlier HP machine which came with Validity VFS 201 sensor and was supported by non-WBF based driver also. The SDK was also available then from Validity when it was not acquired by Authentec. The problem is, I could not find any SDK or support package to integrate this latest sensor with my application OR am I missing out something here? Has anyone integrated this sensor having PID=0050 (when looked up in Device Manager) with his/ her custom application? Help is requested in this regard please.

Thanks....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is totally unclear. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clear. I hope it serves the purpose now.